# Path settings from .bash_profile is not reflected across the system

Tags: linux, gcc, path, export

I have few path settings and alias in .bash_profile, and I am exporting those.

For eg:
alias gcc=/abc/def/......./myrtgcc
export gcc

And I want use **myrtgcc** to compile c programs either from terminal or from eclipse using the command "GCC", and I expect the system to use "myrtgcc" whenever I compile the programs using

> myrtgcc somfile.c -o output

However this is not the case.
even after adding the above alias in .bash_profile, and restarting the system ( or use > source .bash_profile ) the changes are not reflected.

because, If I open the terminal and type

> which gcc

I get **/usr/bin/gcc** and when eclipse uses "GCC" command it again invokes the same **/usr/bin/gcc**.

How do I make **myrtgcc** default across the system, for command **gcc**
Thank you.

Answer (score 1):

1. Make a symbol link in /abc/def/xxx/myrtgcc

   ln -s myrtgcc gcc
2. Put the path of myrtgcc in front of /usr/bin in your .bash_profile:

   export PATH=/abc/def/xxx/myrtgcc:$PATH